# Creating one record for a continuous sequnce of dates to a new table

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

We have a table in Microsoft SQL Server 2014 as shown below which has Id, LogId, AccountId, StateCode, Number and LastSentDate column.

[image]

Our goal was to move the data to a new table. When we move it we need to maintain the first and last record for that series. Based on our data the  lastsentdate starts from 5/1 and continues till 5/5, then we should create a new row as shown below(we set the FirstSentDate as 5/1, Log Id as first log id that appeared - 28369 and since the series ended on 5/5 we update LastsentDate as 5/5 and LastSentLog Id as 28752)

[image]

if there are some dates with the difference in time, the desired output will be

[image]

Since our date series continues the last row in the new table will be

[image]

We were trying to group by date and achieve this

```
WITH t
     AS (SELECT LastSentDate d, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                ORDER BY LastSentDate) i
         FROM [dbo].[RegistrationActivity]
         GROUP BY LastSentDate)
     SELECT MIN(d), 
            MAX(d)
     FROM t
     GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day, i, d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()` to define where a group begins.  Then use a cumulative sum to assign a group id to each group.  And finally, extract the data you want.  I'm not sure what data you actually want, but here is the idea:

```
select accountid, min(lastsentdate), max(lastsentdate)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_lsd > dateadd(day, 1, lastsentdate )then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by accountid order by lastsentdate) as grp
      from (select t.*, lag(lastsentdate) over (partition by accountid) as prev_lsd
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by accountid;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. This helped me to frame the script.